# iOS: Xib View is moving outside the screen from right side

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c, view

I am using Xib view as a common view in header as shown in image

[image]

When user move to next view controller and came back to previous screen it moves out side of screen as shown in image

[image]

I have auto layout the view and given 10 points margin from right side to arrow image. I am not sure why it is moving to right side.

Following is the code:

```
func setHeader(headerView : UIView, vc : UIViewController)
{
    vc1 = vc
    
   
    customView.removeFromSuperview()
    customView = UINib(nibName:"ViewHeader",bundle:.main).instantiate(withOwner: nil, options: nil).first as! HeaderView
    
    customView.btnNotification.setTitle("", for: .normal)
    customView.btnReward.setTitle("", for: .normal)
    customView.btnSideMenu.setTitle("", for: .normal)
    customView.viewUnread.layer.cornerRadius = customView.viewUnread.frame.size.width/2
    customView.viewUnread.clipsToBounds = true

    customView.btnSideMenu.addTarget(self, action: #selector(Commons.openDrawer(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
    customView.lblPoints.text = String(Constants.CUSTOMERPOINTS)
    customView.btnReward.addTarget(self, action: #selector(Commons.openReward(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
    customView.btnNotification.addTarget(self, action: #selector(Commons.openNotification(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
    var w = String(format: "%f", Commons.screenWidth)
    var h = String(format: "%f", Commons.screenHeight)
    print("screenSize ye ha --> height: " + w + " - Width:" + h)
    if(Commons.screenHeight > 400 && Commons.screenHeight <= 750 )
    {
        customView.frame.size.height = 80.0
    }
    else if(Commons.screenHeight > 750 && Commons.screenHeight <= 850 )
    {
      //  customView.ic_centerMargin.constant = -20
        customView.frame.size.height = 80.0
    }
    else if(Commons.screenHeight > 850 && Commons.screenHeight <= 900 )
    {
        customView.frame.size.height = 80.0
    }
    else if (Commons.screenHeight > 900)
    {
        customView.frame.size.height = 80.0
    }
    let group = DispatchGroup()
       group.enter()

    Commons.getPoints()
    { [self] json, error in
               // will be called at either completion or at an error.
             
                           // will be called at either completion or at an error.
        DispatchQueue.main.async { [self] in
            customView.lblPoints.text = String(Constants.CUSTOMERPOINTS)

        }
        group.leave()
           }
       group.wait()
    headerView.addSubview(customView)
   // customView.center = vc1.view.center;
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you create a sample git repo with this issue so that I can try to find a solution. Above code is not giving much hint.
If not, check if the view bounds are coming accurate when you come back to the page, if it is coming wrong then you would have to wait for viewDidLayoutSubviews to complete before adding this subview